# Activiti Project not appear in Eclipse after installing Activiti plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, project, activiti, appearance

Here are the step I followed to install [Activiti](http://activiti.org/) plugin

1. I installed Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

   Version: Kepler Service Release 2

   Build id: 20140224-0627
2. I installed Activiti Plugin through "Install New Software..."

   http://prntscr.com/6bnqxq
3. I restarted Eclipse
4. No Activiti Projects in "File-New-Project".

   http://prntscr.com/6bnrcc

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
First time I installed plugin behind ISA firewall and Eclipse might have problems during installation but didn't inform about them.
Now I made direct connection to Internet and Activiti Project appeared in menu.